# Правильное подключение к mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Критика в пользу подключения к DB :

```
 $db_host = "localhost";
 $db_user = "root";
 $db_pass = "";
 $db_name = "new_db";
 define ("IMG" , "img");

 $link = mysqli_connect($db_host , $db_user , $db_pass , $db_name) OR DIE ("Не могу подключится");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 printf("Ошибка соединения: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
 exit;
 }
 $query = mysqli_select_db($link , $db_name) OR DIE ("Не моу выбрать базу, либо она отсутствует");

$result = mysqli_query($link ,  "SELECT `title` , `text` , `img` FROM `news` ");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{?>
    <div class="post">
        <h2><?= $row['title'];?></h2>
             <img src="IMG/<?= $row['img'];?>" title="" />
            <p><?= $row['text'];?></p>
    </div>
<?}?>
```

что в коде с ошибками , как бы вы улучшили или усовершенствовали ?
код выводит из DB без ошибок , всё работает но:

Comment: И в чем вопрос? Что идет после "но:"?

Comment: допустим , как отделить вью от контроллера ? по отдельности не работает , хоть include хоть include_once

Comment: Чего?! А, понял. Не надо употреблять слова, значения которых ты не понимаешь - это мешает понять, что тебе нужно. Если ты не умеешь пользоваться include, то так и надо писать - мол, проблема с подключением файла в РНР скрипт.

Comment: да вроде я правильно сказал - я могу подробнее объяснить что надо , дело в том что если я делаю файл name.php и в него записываю все $var и делаю include в нужном месте , просто перестаёт работать и всё , а так же само подключение так же в другом файле и так же include и тоже перестаёт рабатать

Comment: Переписывай свой вопрос, показывай, как делаешь include.

Comment: include "connect.php" ; и всё , сложного роде нету ни чего , в этом ошибка ?

Comment: Используйте require_once.

Comment: Dmitry OnGamer  там не через require а надо было  создать function , вы посмотрите мой следующий вопрос - там верный ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поправить в этом коде следует две вещи:

1. Сделать нормальную обработку ошибок.
2. Убрать дублирующийся код.

Таким образом, код подключения будет такой:

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "new_db";

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host , $db_user , $db_pass , $db_name);
```

этот код можно сохранить в файле, и инклюдить его везде, где нужно соединение с БД

Comment: А как убрать сам while с index.php и оставить только {?>  <?}?> вот это ?

Comment: Повторяю, если у тебя проблема с include, то лучше задать новый, отдельный вопрос, который озаглавить "Как правильно использовать include", и описать в нем свои проблемы.