# query("SELECT * FROM table) возвращает пустой объект, хотя таблица есть

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, denwer

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", ""); /// успешное подключение
if ($conn->query("CREATE DATABASE Comics")) {
die ("error: ".$conn->error);
} else {
echo "base created succes<br>";} /// успешное создание базы данных
mysqli_select_db ($conn, "comics"); /// и успешный выбор базы данных
```

`Mysql_select_db("comics")` пишет, что не выбирал базу данных, хотя создать таблицу (команды ниже) в ней и даже добавить строки через `INSERT INTO` получилось. Но не в этом проблема.

```
$conn->query("CREATE TABLE `Villians` (
    id INT(3) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
    byear INT(4)
)"); /// до сюда всё хорошо.
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `villians`"); /// **Вот проблема!!!**
```

Она возвращает пустой объект массив:

```
mysqli_result Object ( )
```

Comment: `if ($conn->query("CREATE DATABASE Comics")) {
die ("error: ".$conn->error);
}` --- что-то тут не то

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, этот кусок закоментирован. Так что не в этом деле, мне кажется. Записи добавляются. Название базы даже добавлял в подключение

Comment: А что вы хотите в этом объекте увидеть? И зачем вообще пытаетесь его выводить?

Comment: @Ипатьев, проверка. Я делаю по курсу itproger на YouTube. И вот там возвращался объект массив со свойствами.  И потом я собирался выводить записи на страницу через цикл.

Comment: Я даже другую таблицу создал, ведь выбирать БД надо было через 'mysqli_select_db', и всё равно не получается. Может, потому что делаю через denwer.

Comment: зачем вообще в пхп создавать БД и таблицы? Что это за идиотский курс? БД и таблицу надо создать ОДИН раз, в консоли. После этого соединиться с БД, делать запрос и выводить записи в цикле.

Comment: и да, почему у вас ВСЕ время разный регистр? Вы не можете как-то взять себя в руки и писать в ЕДИНОМ стиле? желательно без заглавных букв вообще, только маленькими.

Comment: @Ипатьев, оставил только строчку запроса. И строку выбора БД: без этой команды почему-то БД выбранной не остаётся.  Всё равно ничего.

Comment: Чтобы БД была выбрана, надо писать её в mysqli_connect. В общем, надо подключиться, как написано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521623/179379) и потом просто выводить данные из таблицы, без всяких объектов

Comment: @Ипатьев не помогло, хоть и писал базу в коннект. А как без объекта выводить? сначала его присваиваем result (а он получается пустым, значит, уже плохо), потом применяют fetch_assoc().

Comment: ЧТО ЗНАЧИТ "не помогло"? компьютер взорвался? База данных потёрлась? Вам нужно данные вывести? ВЫ КОД для этого написали? Он работает? Если нет, то КАКОЙ ИМЕННО код и КАК ИМЕННО он не работает?

Comment: @Ипатьев, мне удалось вывести данные из таблицы. 
`$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `heroes`");
echo "Strings: ".$result->num_rows. "<br>"; // 
while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo "Name: ". $row['name']. " ";
 echo "the_first_appearance: ". $row[the_first_appear]."<br>";
}`
Я думал, если объект, что в $result пустой (почему? - вопрос) - значит, ничего не получится, ведь в курсе YouTube у преподавателя он не был пустым.  Ан нет, работают свойства num_rows и метод fetch_assoc(), но не fetch_all, он не работает почему-то.
Пишу через Notepad++
Благодарю за участие в проблеме.

Comment: fetch_all не работает потому что денвер значительно старше вас, он вам в дедушки годится. Надо использовать что-то поновее. Чтобы работать с РНР под виндоус надо всего две вещи: скачать и установить mysql как любую другую программу, а потом скачать архив с РНР и распаковать его. Это всё. После этого можно перейти в папку с файлами веб-сервера, запустить веб-сервер командой `c:\путь\к\папке\с\пхп\php.exe -S localhost:80` и ваш сайт будет прекрасно работать

Answer (score 0):

похоже включена чувствительность к регистру [lower_case_table_names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

`CREATE TABLE Villians` тоже не выполняется, просто ошибку не выводит, а дальше просто не находит таблицы при `SELECT * FROM villians`, потому и пустой результат.

Пробуйте названия таблиц и БД одинаково писать.

**upd:**

вот пример, который запускал у себя:

```
//$con = ...

if ($conn->query("CREATE DATABASE Comics")) {
    die ("error: ".$conn->error);
} else {
    echo "\nbase created succes";
}

$r = mysqli_select_db ($conn, "comics");
echo "\nis_connect(comics) : " . ($r ? 'true' : 'false');

$r = mysqli_select_db ($conn, "Comics");
echo "\nis_connect(Comics) : " . ($r ? 'true' : 'false');

$r = $conn->query("CREATE TABLE `Villians` (
    id INT(3) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
    byear INT(4)
)");

// првильное соединение
mysqli_select_db ($conn, "Comics");

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `villians`"); /// **Вот проблема!!!**
echo "\nselect(villians) : " . gettype($result) . ' : ' . ($result ? 'true' : 'false');

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `Villians`"); /// **Вот проблема!!!**
echo "\nselect(Villians) : " . gettype($result). ' : ' . ($result ? 'true' : 'false');
```

на выходе:

```
base created succes
is_connect(comics) : false
is_connect(Comics) : true
select(villians) : boolean : false
select(Villians) : object : true
```

Comment: не помогло, к сожалению

Comment: Благодарю. Данные из таблицы мне вывести удалось - код скинул в комментарий вопроса.